# Does upgrate typescript version in package.json cause some incompatible?

Tags: typescript

I want to update TypeScript version to the latest version in my opensource library. And then I can use some latest features in typescript. Is there any breaking change here? Do other packages which depend on my opensource library will occur some type check error or compile error?

```
For example:

package A: TypeScript: 3.5.3
package B: TypeScript: 3.5.3. Package B depends on Package A

I want to upgrade the package A typescript version to 3.7.4. Is there any incompatible here?
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can check out [releases notes](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/releases) of the required versions and follow [semver semantic versioning](https://semver.org/). Ideally, there should not be any breaking changes between v3.5.3 and v3.7.4, just a new functionality. Everything depends on typescript maintainers and whether they follow semantics.